# How to merge / weld a vertex to an edge without moving it first?

Tags: vertices

If I had an vertex on top of an edge. I know how to merge it by moving it first and the snap it to the edge back, there's a merge option for that. But my question is, can it be merged without moving the vertex first?
Because I have many vertices on top of an edge, it would be tedious if I had to select all the vertices one by one, move them and then snap them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all vertices to get merged, shift select the vertex of the edge (it has to be the active one - last selected), press M and choose "At last".

Comment: I might understand the question wrong, but snapping a vertex to an edge doesn't sound like merging it with one end vertex of an edge... your solution would merge all vertices into one single vertex on one end. If that's what the OP meant I guess this should be clarified in the question.

Comment: The question is about merging, not snapping. Probably he used the automerge option, moving and snapping to merge; he is asking how to merge without moving.

Comment: I know, but still it is misunderstandable what he means since he's talking about snapping to an edge, not a vertex. And also the expression "on top of an edge" leaves some doubt about where he wants to merge.

Comment: Hai everyone Josh Sanfelici's answer is the one I need and he understands my question correctly. 
Thank you all for participating. 
I've been searching for this answer for days.

Comment: @JuanFeju: we are happy Josh could help you. it would be great if you could check the checkmark left to his answer. That's the way here to show this answer fullfilled your needs.